# I am Facing issue in mysql in mac

Tags: python, mysql, django

[image].
while using this command -

pip install mysql

I am facing issue in code in above

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

I try pip3 install mysql

Comment: you can try installing ```pip install mysqlclient```. as mentioned in the readme of mysql https://pypi.org/project/mysql/. it needs mysqlclient.

Comment: Facing Same Problem

Comment: can you elaborate on what you are trying to do, and put the full trace of error.

Comment: I just want to install mysql by terminal and facing issue which are given above , you can easily understand issue by above  screen-short.

Answer (score 0):

This can be because you are using a newer Python version which doesn't support MySQL.

Try to use Python 3.9.

Comment: Not working,Facing Same Problem in mac.

Answer (score 0):

The **mysql** package you are trying to install is not a valid package name, so pip is not able to find it. If you are trying to install a Python connector for MySQL, you should use the **mysql-connector-python** package instead.

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: I just want to install mysql by terminal.Not mysql-connector.

Comment: you want to install mySql by terminal for your system right ?

Comment: Yes Sir and it's mac.